# Dissolving features with two fields and summing values for third field in QGIS

Tags: qgis, dissolve, summarizing, aggregate

I'm trying to dissolve the fields `"Inundation"` and `"EVC_BCS"` (to get the areas of inundation and non-inundation for each rarity category). When I do the dissolve, I would also like to **sum** the field `"AREASQM"` as well.

I've tried using the Plugin "Dissolve with stats", but I've realised that I can only dissolve by one field (not two).

[image]

Thus, I'm quite stuck. How can I dissolve based on two fields whilst summing the `"AREASQM"` field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a possibility using a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`

Let's assume there is a polygon layer called `'grid_test'` (red squares).

[image: input]

With the following query, it is possible *to dissolve two fields while summing a third field*.

```sql
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT("id") AS ids,
       SUM("AREASQM") AS SUM_AREASQM,
       ST_union(geometry) AS geom
FROM "grid_test"
GROUP BY "Inundation", "EVC_BCS"
```

Here the [`ST_Union()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Union.html) function was used.

The output polygon layer (yellow) with its attribute table will look like

[image: result]

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Menu Processing / Toolbox / Aggregate`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?highlight=aggregate#aggregate), where you can set detailed conditions for

1. which fields (based on what condition) should be merged
2. how to deal which each field

For both, the full power of QGIS expressions can be used to generate complex conditions using multiple attributes.

[image]